# Eigenspaces of almost complex structure have the same dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry

Suppose $V^{2n}$ is a real vector space with almost complex structure $J \in End(V)$ i.e. $J^2 = -id$. I look at $V_{\mathbb{C}} : = V \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$, which I know I can also see as $V \oplus i V$ as a $\mathbb{C}$ vector space. Extending $J$ to $V_\mathbb{C}$ in the obvious way yields an endomorphism over $\mathbb{C}$ which is also almost complex.

It's immediate that the eigenvalues of $J \in End(V_\mathbb{C})$ are $\pm i$. Let $V^{1,0}$ be the complex eigenspace of $i$ and $V^{0,1}$ the one of $-i$.

I can see that $V_\mathbb C = V^{0,1} \oplus V^{1,0}$ by writing each $v \in V_\mathbb{C}$ as $v = \frac{v-iJv}{2} + \frac{v+iJv}{2} \in V^{0,1} + V^{1,0}$ and the sum is obviously direct.

However, I can't see why $\dim_\mathbb C V^{1,0} = \dim_ \mathbb C V^{0,1}$. I tried defining an isomorphism $\phi: V^{1,0} \rightarrow V^{0,1}$ between them, but I can't see how. Simply multiplying by a $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ wouldn't work as I'd want
$
J \phi(v) = -i \phi(v)
$, but this means $\lambda i v = -\lambda i v$ so $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: The characteristic polnomial of $J$ over $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ are the same. In particular, complex roots come in pairs. You will probably no be able to find the isomorphism you are looking for because it seems completely non-canonical

Comment: I know that about the roots, but why would the eigenspaces have the same dimension?

Comment: Let me rephrase the idea: Put the matrix in diagonal form and compute its characteristic polynomial. The have to be the same $i$ and $-i$ for this to be a polynomial with real coefficients

Comment: So you're saying that the eigenspaces have the same dimensions because the polynomial has real coefficients? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @rosecabbagedragon Because $J$ is diagonalizable, the dimension of each eigenspace is equal to the exponent of the corresponding term in the characteristic polynomial. Because the characteristic polynomial has real coefficients, all of its roots from $\Bbb C \setminus \Bbb R$ must come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: Yes, as @BenGrossmann said